# Example wavefunction of a squeezed spin state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Can someone give me a "simplest possible" exact example wavefunction of a spin-state that is squeezed?

The usual example is a coherent states, but they are a bit tricky to work with and get intuition from, so I'm hoping for a simpler example with, say, two spin-1/2 particles, where the wavefunction should be pretty easy to just explicitly write down, assuming that it's possible.

Comment: Coherent spin states tend to have definite particle numbers. What do you mean, exactly, by asking for states that aren't coherent states?

Comment: Hmm, my thoughts on coherent spin states appear to have been a bit jumbled. I've rephrased my question.